# onActivityResult is not called in android

Tags: android

I am making a mobile app, Here I want to take a number from contact. When i click on contact imageview then mobile contact is open then i select a number.After then mob_no edittext is blank that means onActivityResult is not called, I am also print the value of resultcode, requestcode and data, but it is not executed. Please solve my problem how to call onActivityResult(...)

```
public class Recharge_activity extends Activity{

private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

mob_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobilenum);
        mob_no.requestFocus();
        contact = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_contact);

mob_no.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

            contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{


                        Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
                        pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers

                        startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, 1);

                    } catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(Recharge_activity.this, "Number is not format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();

                    String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, projection, null, null, null);   
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
                    int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                    String number = cursor.getString(column);

                    String newNum = number.replaceAll("-", "").trim();

                    newNum=newNum.replace("+91", "");

                    mob_no.setText(newNum);
                    }
        }
    }
    private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //after text changed


            if (count==0)
            {
                counter=counter-1;
            }else if(count==1)
            {
                counter = count + counter;
            }


            if(counter!=0)
            {
                if(counter==6 && count==1)
                {
                    spinner.setEnabled(true);
                cont_no=mob_no.getText().toString();
                setfillspinner();

                }

                if(counter<5)
                {
                    provider_name.clear();
                    spinner.setEnabled(false);
                    provider_name.add("Select Operator");
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Recharge_activity.this

                            ,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, provider_name);
                    System.out.println("value call double time");

                                 // Set the Adapter
                    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    //amt.setFocusable(true);
                    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    spinner.setSelection(0);

                }


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not being called? Use `Log` to log a message in the `onActivityResult(...)` method and log the result code.

Comment: Is the calling activity singleInstance? Does it have noHistory flag in manifest? If any of those true, then remove it.

Comment: i am also use Log, but for that reason i am saying onActivityResult(...) method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
       //put your code here
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Edit answer

```
  Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
                    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers

                    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, 1);
```

Comment: This code is also not work. Here main problem is onActivityResult is not called. if write the code @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) // TODO Auto-generated method stub{ System.out.println("the value request code" + requestCode);
    System.out.println("the value resultCode" + resultCode);
    System.out.println("the value data" + data); } that code is not run.

Comment: it shows error "The constructor Intent(Recharge_activity, Uri) is undefined"

Comment: try with this. chnage Recharge_activity.this to getApplicationContext();

Comment: it is also shows error "The constructor Intent(Context, Uri) is undefined"

Comment: there no constructor in intent with context and uri ...just pass action and uri.

Answer (score 0):

Are you set permission  in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```